# vue:Syntax Error: await is a reserved word

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
async checkDriver(mobile) {
    this.$axios({
      url: "xxx",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        mobile: mobile
      }
    }).then(res => {
      console.log("========="+res.status);
      return res.data.status;
    }).catch(error => {
      this.$message.error(error.toString());
      return -1;
    });
  },
  addValidate() {
    this.$refs['form'].validate((valid) => {
      if (valid) {
        let status = await this.checkDriver(this.form.mobile);
        console.log(status);

      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Unresolved variable or type await.Highlights functions that were possibly intended to be async but are missing the async modifier.How to use await in =>?Give me some help.Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `async` keyword must be used for the function that USES await in its body.

So, move `async` from `checkDriver` to `addValidate`:

```
checkDriver(mobile) {
    // ...
}
async addValidate() {
    // ...
    let status = await this.checkDriver(this.form.mobile);
}
```

Also, the `checkDriver` method should return a promise. So change the contents of `checkDriver` to:

```
checkDriver(mobile) {
    return this.$axios({
        url: "xxx",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            mobile: mobile
        }
    })
}
```

and the data returned from the Promise (axios in this case) will be assigned to `status` in `addValidate`

Then if you want to handle errors, you should wrap the `await` call in a try/catch block.

Answer (score 3):

```js
addValidate() {
    this.$refs['form'].validate( async (valid) => {
      if (valid) {
        let status = await this.checkDriver(this.form.mobile);
        console.log(status);

      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
```

You can add the missing `async` keyword beside the parameter

Comment: This result is:console.log(status);console.log("========="+res.status);

Answer (score 0):

You must make `addValidate()` async, like `async addValidate() { /* ... */ }`. You can only [use `await` in a function that's marked `async`](http://thecodebarbarian.com/80-20-guide-to-async-await-in-node.js.html#hello-world).